# How to write custom event ID to the Event Log using Serilog?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

It's easy to use Serilog to log events to the Windows Event Log, however the same sink appears not to offer the ability to write a custom event ID with the log.  So if we decide to use Event ID 4000 for our app, how do we configure Serilog to write that Event ID to the event log with the source, description etc?

Answer (score 0):

To customize the `EventID`, you have to implement your own [`IEventIdProvider`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/IEventIdProvider.cs#L22) and [tell the sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/LoggerConfigurationEventLogExtensions.cs#L108) to use your provider instead of the [default one](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/EventIdHashProvider.cs#L23).

```
.WriteTo(..., eventIdProvider: yourProvider)
```

---

```
    public static LoggerConfiguration EventLog(
        this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
        string source,
        string logName = null,
        string machineName = ".",
        bool manageEventSource = false,
        string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
        IFormatProvider formatProvider = null,
        LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum,
        IEventIdProvider eventIdProvider = null) // <#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Where do you specify the Event number? i.e. 4000?

Comment: I confess I'm quite new to .NET, do you have an example I could follow?

Comment: @MarcusT-M I linked the implementation of the default event provider above: [EventIdHashProvider.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/EventIdHashProvider.cs#L39)... Just replace the code in the `Compute` method.